# How the handle an override of the schema of a field type

Tags: updating

To add other data to a `state` field, I overrode 2 functions of the StateItem class (from the state_item module)

```
    public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
        $schema=StateItem::schema($field_definition);
        $schema['columns']['json']=[
            'type' => 'json',
            'pgsql_type' => 'json',
            'mysql_type' => 'json',
            'not null' => FALSE,
            'description' => "Store data about states in json format",
        ];
        return $schema;
     }
    public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
        $properties=parent::propertyDefinitions($field_definition);
        $properties['json']=DataDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('Data'));
        return $properties;
    }
```

As I have already several fields of this type in my website, I got the following errors in the `Status report` page:

```
Entity/field definitions  Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
                          The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
```

...followed by the fields that must be updated.

Knowing the fact that I am the only user of this custom field, what is the best approach to handle this kind of change?

**Here is the solution**

As explained by @sanzante, I created an UpdateN function which is updating all the fields of the `state` type by adding an appropriate column to the table of each field:

```
function mymodule_update_8001() {
  $spec = [
    'type' => 'json',
    'pgsql_type' => 'json',
    'mysql_type' => 'json',
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'description' => "Store data about states in json format",
  ];
  $schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
  $state_fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')
    ->getFieldMapByFieldType('state');
  foreach ($state_fields as $entity_type_id => $fields) {
    foreach (array_keys($fields) as $field_name) {
      $table = $entity_type_id . '__' . $field_name;
      $table_rev = $entity_type_id.'_revision' . '__' . $field_name;
      $new_field_name = $field_name . '_json';
      $schema->addField($table, $new_field_name, $spec);
      $schema->addField($table_rev, $new_field_name, $spec);
    }
  }

}
```

The key points are :

1-how the table names are constructed. (see `$table` and `$table_rev` in the code)

2-how the new field names are constructed. (see `$new_field_name` in the code an the fact that you must use the same column name as defined in `$schema['columns']['json']`)

3-You must use the same spec as the ones defined in `function schema`

After the updated ran, I still got the `Mismatched entity and/or field definitions` error message.

I could solve this by running `drush entup` (the module `devel_entity_updates` must be installed)

Comment: For mismatched entities, you can also module Devel Entity Updates - https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates (be very careful with this module because it can cause loss of data, so handle with care).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write an update function that changes those fields live in your database so they match the new definition.

Time ago, this was done using the `drush entity-updates` command. However, this was dangerous in some circumstances. You can check the [Support for automatic entity updates has been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742) change record to get more information on this.

In this change record you can see:

> Starting with 8.7.0, Drupal core no longer provides support for
> automatic entity updates. Whenever an entity type or field storage
> definition needs to be created, changed or deleted, it has to be done
> with an explicit update function as provided by the Update API, and
> using the API provided by the entity definition update manager.

Therefore, you need an update function. Probably, you should read the "[Updating Database Schema and/or Data in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-database-schema-andor-data-in-drupal-8)" page, specially the "[Adding a new column](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-database-schema-andor-data-in-drupal-8#s-adding-a-new-column)" section:

> Here's an example of what to put into your hook_update_N() function to
> add a new column to an existing database table:
>
> ```
>   $spec = [
>     'type' => 'varchar',
>     'description' => "New Col",
>     'length' => 20,
>     'not null' => FALSE,
>   ]; 
>  $schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
>  $schema->addField('mytable1', 'newcol', $spec);
> ```

**Devel Entity Updates module**

As pointed out by @Ales, you may try the [Devel Entity Updates module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates):

> This command should be able to fully replace the legacy drush entup or
> drush entity-updates commands.

However, this module is not meant to be used in production environments, see the following disclaimer from the module:

> The goal of this module is to have a quick way to apply schema updates
> while developing new entity types and ending up incrementally
> adding/removing/changing entity type/field definitions.
>
> When these changes are part of an official release (and not in the
> scope of a code development session), they should absolutely rely on
> DB update functions, as explained in the CR above, because that's the
> only way the entity schema update process can be predictable and
> reliable.

So, this approach is ok for you if don't have a production environment yet. Of course, you can ignore the warning and install the module on prod, but keep in mind that you may lose data because the operation is not safe.

You can try it on a test environment, and if you finally take the risk and use in prod make sure you have a recent backup at hand.

**Why you need this**

The problem you have a difference between the table data definition in code and the actual data tables in your database. Why does this happen? There are different circumstances that can lead to this. In your case, the State module has some data definitions that are applied when the module is installed. At this point, code data definition and actual data tables are matching. However, if you make any changes on the code that defines the data tables the problem arises: you have one definition on code and different actual data tables in the database.

So what you need to do is modify the tables to match the data definition. That's what my answer tries to explain. The two methods are writing an update function (so you control with that function how to modify the actual tables) or trust an automatic method (the entity update command). The command is easy but it has no brain so it just modifies the tables without thinking on possible issues. That's why you may have problems (data loss, mainly) using that command.

Comment: sorry for my late answer. I have accepted yours and you get the bounties. I have also added the code for my use case if anybody needs. If you have time, could you tell me why I had to ran ´drush entup´ after having added the columns? [see last part of my question] Is it what was expected?

Comment: Updated my answer with the section "Why you need this", I hope it explains what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but it was not my question. I fully understand the difference between the manual table change vs `drush entup`. My question is: I ran an `updateN` function with `$schema->addField()` in it. After that I could see the added columns in my tables but still get the mismatch problem. I solved it by running `drush entup`. Maybe there is something else to take care (I mean something else than `$schema->addField()`)

Comment: I guess you forgot to apply some change in your update function. I'm not sure, but in your code you define a property (function `propertyDefinitions`). That is not added in your update function. It could be that.

Comment: This should be what I missed. Do you mind to link to a doc on how to handle this added property in a `updatedN` function.

Comment: I think is this one: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/update-api/updating-entities-and-fields-in-drupal-8#s-other-examples

Comment: ok, thank you... I think I get it: `BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')`  should handle the new property: `DataDefinition::create('string')` and the newly created BaseFieldDefinition must be installed with `$definition_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition()` . In my case, no need to replace de values.